# How to get the tail of a range in Elixir

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

This is probably a trivial question but I can't get my head around it.

I just want to pattern match on a range, getting the head and tail.

Here's what I tried:

```
iex(1)> [h|t] = [1..3]
[1..3]
iex(2)> h
1..3
iex(3)> t
[]
```

As you can see, it doesn't do what I expected. My expectation was `h = 1` and `t = [2,3]`.

How do I get head and tail out of a range? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `[1..3]` is a list containing 1 range, not a range. Second, a range itself is not a list, it's just a struct containing 2 values: the first and the last value (`Map.from_struct(1..10) #=> %{first: 1, last: 10}`). If you want the head and tail of a range as lists, you need to convert the range to a list first:

```
iex(1)> range = 1..3
1..3
iex(2)> list = Enum.to_list(range)
[1, 2, 3]
iex(3)> [h | t] = list
[1, 2, 3]
iex(4)> h
1
iex(5)> t
[2, 3]
```

Note that this is very inefficient depending on what you're doing. A range occupies very little memory (a Struct + 2 integer keys). A list will occupy space proportionate to the number of items in the list. Depending on what you're doing, there might be a better way than converting the range to a list.

Answer (score 7):

This should work better

```
iex(42)> range = 1..100     
1..100
iex(43)> _..last = range    
1..100
iex(44)> last
100
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know you could do that. +1

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is probably to just grab it from the underlying AST:

```
iex(6)> Macro.escape(1..10)
{:%{}, [], [__struct__: Range, first: 1, last: 10]}
```

Thus...

```
{:%{}, [], [__struct__: Range, first: head, last: tail]} = Macro.escape(range)

iex(10)> head
1
iex(11)> tail
10
```

---

edit: was using `quote` but `Macro.escape` seems to be more robust here

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last item of a range by it's index

```
iex(1)> range = 1..3                      
1..3
iex(2)> last_index = Enum.count(range) - 1
2
iex(3)> Enum.at(range, last_index)        
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from edwinallenz's answer (elegant but returns only the last element) the following returns head and tail while also staying close to the OP's idea:

```
iex(1)> first..last = 1..5
1..5
iex(2)> [h | t] = [first | first+1..last]
[1 | 2..5]
```

Dogbert's answer explains the syntactic sugar on Elixir ranges: take off the makeup and underneath `1..5` you'll find the struct `%Range{first: first, last: last}`. 
So, the above using the underlying struct directly would be this unwieldy thing:

```
iex(1)> r = %Range{first: 1, last: 5}     
1..5
iex(2)> [h | t] = [r.first | %Range{first: r.first+1, last: r.last}]
[1 | 2..5]
```